# Find most common occurrence among a set of variables by key in data.table in R

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, apply

I am trying to find the most common occurrence among a set of variables by a key in a `data.table` in R.  Here is a small example of what I'm trying to do:

```
library(data.table)

mydata <- data.table(mergedName=c("JOHNDOE","JOHNDOE","JOHNDOE","MARYWHITE","MARYWHITE","MARYWHITE","JOHNDOE","JOHNDOE","JOHNDOE","MARYWHITE","MARYWHITE","MARYWHITE"),
                     job=c("teacher","teacher","teacher","teacher","teacher","teacher","police","police","police","police","police","police"),
                     from=c("NYT","USAT","BG","NYT","USAT","BG","NYT","USAT","BG","NYT","USAT","BG"),
                     misspelled_NYT=c("John Doe", NA, NA, "Mary White", NA, NA,"John_Doe", NA, NA, "Mary*White", NA, NA),
                     misspelled_USAT=c(NA, "JohnDOE", NA, NA, "Mary White", NA, NA, "John Doe", NA, NA, "Mary White", NA),
                     misspelled_BG=c(NA, NA, "John Doe", NA, NA, "Mary-White", NA, NA, "John Doe", NA, NA, "Mary White"))

setkeyv(mydata, cols=c("mergedName","job"))
```

Here's the `data.table` object:

```
> mydata
    mergedName     job from misspelled_NYT misspelled_USAT misspelled_BG
 1:    JOHNDOE teacher  NYT       John Doe              NA            NA
 2:    JOHNDOE teacher USAT             NA         JohnDOE            NA
 3:    JOHNDOE teacher   BG             NA              NA      John Doe
 4:  MARYWHITE teacher  NYT     Mary White              NA            NA
 5:  MARYWHITE teacher USAT             NA      Mary White            NA
 6:  MARYWHITE teacher   BG             NA              NA    Mary-White
 7:    JOHNDOE  police  NYT       John_Doe              NA            NA
 8:    JOHNDOE  police USAT             NA        John Doe            NA
 9:    JOHNDOE  police   BG             NA              NA      John Doe
10:  MARYWHITE  police  NYT     Mary*White              NA            NA
11:  MARYWHITE  police USAT             NA      Mary White            NA
12:  MARYWHITE  police   BG             NA              NA    Mary White
```

Here's the output I'm expecting (the most common name spelling across each of the three sources for each keyed combination of `mergedName` & `job`):

```
    mergedName     job actualSpelling
 1:    JOHNDOE teacher       John Doe
 2:    JOHNDOE teacher       John Doe
 3:    JOHNDOE teacher       John Doe
 4:    JOHNDOE  police       John Doe
 5:    JOHNDOE  police       John Doe
 6:    JOHNDOE  police       John Doe
 7:  MARYWHITE teacher     Mary White
 8:  MARYWHITE teacher     Mary White
 9:  MARYWHITE teacher     Mary White
10:  MARYWHITE  police     Mary White
11:  MARYWHITE  police     Mary White
12:  MARYWHITE  police     Mary White
```

I have been able to do this with data frames in wide form.  Here is a small example of the code for doing this in wide form---NOTE: for some reason this seemingly works only on larger data frames, it does not work in the example below, even though the code is the same.  The `table()` output applied across rows to this DF is different from what I'd expect.:

```
mydataWide <- data.frame(mergedName=c("JOHNDOE","MARYWHITE","JOHNDOE","MARYWHITE"),
                         job=c("teacher","police","teacher","police"),
                         misspelled_NYT=c("John Doe", "Mary White", "John_Doe", "Mary*White"),
                         misspelled_USAT=c("JohnDOE", "Mary White", "John Doe", "Mary White"),
                         misspelled_BG=c("John Doe", "Mary-White", "John Doe", "Mary White"),
                         stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

nametable <- apply(mydataWide[,paste("misspelled", c("NYT","USAT","BG"), sep="_")], 1, function(x) sort(table(x), decreasing=TRUE))
mydataWide$actualSpelling <- names(sapply(nametable,`[`, 1) )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could first `melt` the `mydata` to `long` form, remove the `NA` rows using `na.omit`, find the `max` count of `actualSpelling` (grouped by `mergedName` and `job`) using `which.max` and `table`.  Use the numeric index to get the terms with max frequency.

```
 library(data.table)
 melt(mydata, id.vars=c('mergedName', 'job'), measure.vars=4:6,
    na.rm=TRUE, value.name='actualSpelling')[,
      actualSpelling:= names(which.max(table(actualSpelling))), 
      by=list(mergedName, job)][order(mergedName), -3]


 #   mergedName     job actualSpelling
 #1:    JOHNDOE  police       John Doe
 #2:    JOHNDOE teacher       John Doe
 #3:    JOHNDOE  police       John Doe
 #4:    JOHNDOE teacher       John Doe
 #5:    JOHNDOE  police       John Doe
 #6:    JOHNDOE teacher       John Doe
 #7:  MARYWHITE  police     Mary White
 #8:  MARYWHITE teacher     Mary White
 #9:  MARYWHITE  police     Mary White
#10:  MARYWHITE teacher     Mary White
#11:  MARYWHITE  police     Mary White
#12:  MARYWHITE teacher     Mary White
```

Comment: On `melt`'s syntax, you could do: `melt(mydata, id.vars=1:2, measure.vars=4:6, na.rm=TRUE)` - of course using column names would be safer. Then no need to `subset` or `na.omit`.